# Why aren't my Omnibox suggestions redirecting to another page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension that suggests some results in the suggestions box.

I can see the suggestions as I should but when I click on one of them nothing happens. The same also goes to the default suggestions. I'm getting an error in the console saying.

The error somehow looks like its in the code google wrote that compiles this.

> Uncaught Error: error on line 1 at column 16: EntityRef: expecting ';'
>   extensions::omnibox:41

**Here is the code:**

```
  chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(function(text, suggest){

  var suggestions = [];
  var omdbAPI = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?'  + 's=' + text.split(' ').join('+');
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', omdbAPI , true);
  req.send();
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {

      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      if(data.Response == "True"){
        data.Search.map(function(a){
          suggestions.push({
            description: a.Title + ' (' +a.Year + ')',
            content: 'www.imdb.com/title/' + a.imdbID
          });
        });
        console.log(suggestions);
        suggest(suggestions);
      }
    }
  }

  chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion(
    {
      description:  'Search on IMDB: ' + text
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Your error indicates that you're missing a ';' semicolon somewhere.

Comment: @noogui How can the missing semicolon be in my code if the error indicates that its in Googe's code, even though that's probably not true?

Comment: @Swailem95 Although the top of the stack is in Chrome's code, the cause of the error is in your input. You can see that Chrome attempts to parse your input and throws if it is not valid XML: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/180e7e74926ea32ac039821926542452d1201c5e/chrome/renderer/resources/extensions/omnibox_custom_bindings.js#41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to happen when an option is clicked, register a listener for the [`chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox#event-onInputEntered) event.

As for the error,

> Uncaught Error: error on line 1 at column 16: EntityRef: expecting ';'
>   extensions::omnibox:41

This error message is caused by the invalid XML in the [`description` property of the suggestion](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox#type-SuggestResult). From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The text that is displayed in the URL dropdown. Can contain XML-style markup for styling. The supported tags are 'url' (for a literal URL), 'match' (for highlighting text that matched what the user's query), and 'dim' (for dim helper text). The styles can be nested, eg. dimmed match. **You must escape the five predefined entities to display them as text: [stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/89484](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents/1091953#1091953)**

Lastly, I've already created an extension that provides search suggestions for searches on IMDB, see https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imdb-search/cbongpcdgehbfeajgkndgkbdkkfdmdik.
You can take a look at the source code for some inspiration, or install it if it fits your needs. To view or download the source code, the [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) can be used (also by me).

Comment: I just added the onInputedEntered listener and the suggestions are working as they should and they are redirecting to the correct page, however the default suggestion doesnt.

Comment: Yes I did. I looked through your code but I couldn't find exactly where you were doing this and I resolved the error by validating the XML similar to what you did in your (overly-complex) code.

Comment: @Swailem95 The two parts of my answer that address your question is the first line and the boldfaced text in the middle. The code was only provided to show how I directly used IMDB's API (not some third-party one) to retrieve the results (with caching and error-handling). The actual omnibox logic is the few dozen lines at the bottom of the file, and far from complex. If you don't understand it, just stick to the rest of the answer.

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same thing to the regular suggestions and they're redirecting when clicked. I'm not getting an errors either, im just being redirected to chrome-extension://myExtensionID/searchTerm

Comment: @Swailem95 Can you provide a link to your extension and/or source code?

Comment: I just updated the code in the question with the source code.

Comment: `chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered` doesn't receive a URL, but the input text. See the bottom of my extension's source code for an example (CTRL+F `onInputEntered`).

Comment: Yep, fixed it. Thanks!